# Get single value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array result

```
Array ( [0] => Item Object ( [name:protected] => My Super Cool Toy [price:protected] =>      10.99 ) )
```

I need to get `[name:protected] => My Super Cool Toy` from this array.

Please tell me how to get it,

I will paste my classes below

```
class ShoppingCart
{
private $items = array();
private $n_items = 0;
function addItem( Item $item )
{
$this->items[] = $item;
$this->n_items = $this->n_items + 1;
print_r($this->items);

}
}
```

and

```
class Item {
protected $name;
protected $price;

 public function __construct($name, $price) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
}

public function getName() {
    echo "item is $this->name";
    return $this->name;
}

public function getPrice() {
    return $this->price;
}

}
```

and

```
require_once('AddingMachine.php');
require_once('item.php');
//$arrayofnumbers = array(100,200);

$objectname = new ShoppingCart();
$objectname->addItem(new Item('My Super Cool Toy', 10.99));

 $obname = new Item($items,44);
$obname->getName();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you got this array in ShoppingCart class, in method addItem, so to access it you just use corresponding getter method, e.g.:

```
$this->items[0]->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$objectname = new ShoppingCart();
$objectname->addItem(new Item('My Super Cool Toy', 10.99));

foreach ( $objectname->getItems() as $item ) {
    echo $item->getName(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Modified Class

```
class ShoppingCart {
    private $items = array();
    private $n_items = 0;

    function addItem(Item $item) {
        $this->items[] = $item;
        $this->n_items = $this->n_items + 1;
    }

    function getItems($n = null) {
        return $n === null ? $this->items : (isset($this->items[$n]) ?  : $this->items[$n]);
    }
}
```